# TextOnly jquery select2 input

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to create a **jQuery Select2** input form element where the input will only take text values not numbers neither special characters.

I tried using html pattern presented in its official documentation page to no avail.

Please help me put a alphabetic-only constraint on a jQuery Select2 form field.

Comment: See if this helps. <input name="lorem" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/g,'');"> Can you please paste some code snippet which you have tried

Comment: can you add your html and jquery here

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,''));

if(event.which < 97 /* a */ || event.which > 122 /* z */) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```js
$(".select2").select2({
    tags: true,
    allowClear: true
});

$(document).on('keypress', '.select2-search__field', function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,''));

     if(event.which < 97 /* a */ || event.which > 122 /* z */) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class='select2' style='min-width: 100px;'>
  <option/>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>White</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
  <option>Read</option>
</select>
```